# RouteTable.Routes.Ignore() doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing

I have a problem when using URL routing in asp.net which is the pictures added to the page being routed aren't displayed. I used:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{*allpng}", new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
```

but it's not working. I also used:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
```

but an error occurs that is: the name 'routes' doesn't exist in the current context.

Could someone please help me to solve the problem ?
(Note: I'm not using MVC application)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Phil's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx) regarding this.

In ASP.NET Web Forms, use [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler.aspx) which implements IRouteHandler.

```
routes.Add(new Route("*someregextoignorewhatyouwant*", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It shows me an error: 'routes' doesn't exist in the current context. Mr. Phill's way is good but same problem in routes, it doesn't exist in the current context. Could you give me a solution to that please ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
<script language="javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/file path")%>" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```